# Свойство object-fit: cover; для IE и Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Есть ли какая-то возможность заставить свойство `object-fit: cover;` работать с IE и Edge? Знаю что есть штука с названием Polyfill, не знаю что с ней делать. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с `object-fit: cover;` для IE и Edge.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать следующий хак: поставить изображение фоном к блоку и применить к нему свойство `background-size: cover`, которое работает и в IE и Edge. Этот вариант будет на чистом CSS и будет работать гораздо быстрее полифилов на JS.

Однако если действительно нужно использовать `img`, вы можете применить полифил для IE:

```js
var Detect = {
init: function () {
    this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser);
},
searchString: function (data) {
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var dataString = data[i].string;
        var dataProp = data[i].prop;
        this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
        if (dataString) {
            if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
        else if (dataProp)
            return data[i].identity;
    }
},
dataBrowser: [
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "MSIE",
        identity: "IE",
        versionSearch: "MSIE"
    }
]
};
Detect.init();

if(Detect.browser == 'IE'){
   var bgImg = document.querySelector("#bg img");
   imgUrl = bgImg.getAttribute('src');
   bg.innerHTML += '<div class="img" style="background-image: url(' + imgUrl + ')">';
}
```

```css
#bg{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#bg img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#bg .img{
    background: #fff no-repeat 50% / cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="bg">
        <img src="https://1000.tech/img/bg0.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю, в данном случае картинки не индексируются, поэтому не уверен, что это будет лучше чем полифил
Но быстрее всего так и буду делать, спасибо